# Let R be the region bounded by the parabola , $y=x^2$, and the line , $y=16$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let R be the region bounded by the parabola , $y=x^2$; and the line , $y=16$;.  (a) What is the volume of the solid generated when R is rotated about the line, $y=16$ ?

I'm really lost here.

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture. The radius of the circle of cross-section at $x$ is $16-x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Our method is Dishwasher: $r = 16-x^2 \to V = \displaystyle \int_{-4}^{4} \pi(16-x^2)^2dx$